# Creating Comments with Ajax/Rails - NameError

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Trying to use Ajax for some nifty instant-appearing comment creation on my reddit-type app. Still trying to get a hang of ruby syntax though. I'm having trouble integrating my form partial with my comments controller. I'm coming up with a NameError, particularly:

undefined local variable or method `post' for #<#:0x007f8e36d05d88>

I have some vague idea how to troubleshoot it (somewhere where I initialize variables in the comments controller?) but haven't been able to apply a working solution.

Here is my corresponding _form.html.rb partial for my comments.

```
 <%= form_for [post, post.comments.build], remote: true do |f| %>
    <% if post.errors.any? %>
     <div class="alert alert-danger">
       <h4>There are <%= pluralize(post.errors.count, "error") %>.</h4>
       <ul>
         <% post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
           <li><%= msg %></li>
         <% end %>
       </ul>
     </div>
   <% end %>
   <%= form_group_tag(post.errors[:body]) do %>
     <%= f.label :body %>
     <%= f.text_area :body, rows: 1, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter comment" %>
   <% end %>
   <div class="form-group">
     <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
   </div>
 <% end %>
```

here is my comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comments = @post.comments

    @comment = current_user.comments.build( comment_params )
    @comment.post = @post
    @new_comment = Comment.new

    authorize @comment

    if @comment.save
      flash[:notice] = "Comment was saved"
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the comment. Please try again."
    end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    authorize @comment

    if @comment.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Comment was removed."
    else
      flash[:error] = "Comment couldn't be deleted. Try again"
    end

    respond_to do |format|
       format.html
       format.js
    end
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

Any constructive input is appreciated. Please let me know if you need additional views for different directories. Thank you in advance!

*requested view from comment thread (comments/create.js.erb file)

```
<% if @comment.valid? %>
   $('.js-comments').prepend("<%= escape_javascript(render(@comment)) %>");
   $('.new-comment').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'comments/form', locals: { post: @post, comment: @new_comment }) %>");
 <% else %>
   $('.new-comment').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'comments/form', locals: { post: @post, comment: @comment }) %>");
 <% end %>
```

Comment: How are you calling that partial? Show us that code.

Comment: done. please see above.

Answer (score 1):

Your form on the view should be this

```
 <%= form_for [@post, @post.comments.build], remote: true do |f| %>
    <% if @post.errors.any? %>
     <div class="alert alert-danger">
       <h4>There are <%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %>.</h4>
       <ul>
         <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
           <li><%= msg %></li>
         <% end %>
       </ul>
     </div>
   <% end %>
   <%= form_group_tag(@post.errors[:body]) do %>
     <%= f.label :body %>
     <%= f.text_area :body, rows: 1, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter comment" %>
   <% end %>
   <div class="form-group">
     <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
   </div>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change post to @post as:

```
<% if @comment.valid? %>
  $('.js-comments').prepend("<%= escape_javascript(render(@comment)) %>");
  $('.new-comment').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'comments/form', locals: { @post: @post, comment: @new_comment }) %>");
<% else %>
  $('.new-comment').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'comments/form', locals: { @post: @post, comment: @comment }) %>");
<% end %>
```

And in your form do as:

```
 <%= form_for [@post, @post.comments.build], remote: true do |f| %>
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you declare the instance variable `@post`. But in your view you are using the local variable `post`. Instance variables belong to objects while local variables have plain old lexical scope.

Rails takes all the instance variables from the controller and exports them into what is called the view context. Which is why the they seem to magically appear. This often confuses beginners.